# converting tcl to perl to format date time

Tags: perl, tcl

I need to convert my TCL script to perl, i know bit of perl but not much:

I needed to convert this line to perl:

```
set current [clock format [clock scan "1 hour ago" -base [clock seconds]] -format "%Y-%m-%d %H"]
```

It prints the current date and 1 hour behind( Since the server returns EST, i want CST).

For example if today's date was 07/31/2012 and the time was 4:20pm(5:20pm EST) it would print

2012-07-31 16

The server returns eastern time, therefore I want it to print 1 hour ago to adjust to central time.
Note : it should not print 16:20.

Comment: @Cfreak It sets the `current` variable to the string that is `year-month-day hour` from one hour ago.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
use POSIX qw/strftime/;

print strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', localtime);
# prints 2012-07-31 14 for me, currently
```

EDIT:  If you have to get this format for one hour ago, then do this instead:

```
use POSIX qw/strftime/;

my $hour_ago = time() - (60*60);
print strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', localtime($hour_ago));
# prints 2012-07-31 13 for me, currently
```

And if it's a time zone issue, you might want consider dealing with the time zone explicitly, rather than assuming a one hour offset.  Here's an [article on handling time zones in Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=659153).

Comment: @Qsario.Sorry, since the server returns EASTERN time, it prints 17, but i want it to print 16 as per CST